# How to search in complex javaScript array object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I am a bit confused. I have the following code in the directive:

```js
NavTabsDirective.prototype.addPane = function (pane) {
        if (!_.isObject(pane) || "Pane" !== pane.constructor.name) {
            throw new TypeError("pane must be an instance of Pane");
        }

        if (_.isUndefined(this.FirstPane)) {
            this.FirstPane = pane;
        }
        
        this.Panes[pane.name] = pane;
    };
```

when I look in the debugger at the this.Panes array, I see something like:

```
this.Panes[name1] = paneObject -- with properties
this.Panes[name2] = paneObject -- with its properties
```

I want to understand how to search this array. Say, this is my code:

```
let invalid = (_.findIndex(this.Panes, { 'isValid': false })>=0);
```

which I commented out as it could not find a pane where isValid is false although I can see such pane in that array.

So, my confusion comes from the fact that the Panes array object has names to access each pane object and so I don't know how to properly search it. How would I check for invalid among the panes?

Answer (score 1):

Unless `pane.name` is a number the panes in this.panes is not an array, it's an object, you can use it's keys and reduce it to a value:

```
const result = Object.keys(this.Panes).reduce(
  (all,key)=>all && this.Panes[key].isValid,
  true
)
```

Comment: I was able to come up with a similar solution last night, see my answer to myself. I have to slightly adjust it and pass back the array of invalid tabs and not just the status, but the idea was to use for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution after checking few threads here:

```js
for (let pane in this.Panes) {
                if (this.Panes[pane].isValid === false) {
                    invalid = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
```

It works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var Panes = ["Hello","World"];
var PanesLength = Panes.length;
for (var i = 0; i < PanesLength; i++) {
    if(Panes[i] == "Hello"){
      alert(Panes[i]);
    }
}
```